# How do I create a view that will not follow the site.css template?

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, view

I am trying to create an asp.net MVC website and noticed that every view I create always has the header at the top and footer at the bottom due to the shared layout template. Is there a way to create a view that wont follow the template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use multiple layouts.
Just create a second layout without the css reference.

You can specify layouts at the top of your view like this :

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_PublicLayout.cshtml";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this a ton of ways.  Here are the two most common ways.

In your controller you can..

```
return this.PartialView(model);
```

or in your View you can (I don't recommend this..)

```
@{
  Layout = null;
}
```